# find a library that manages multi-selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I develop a web application, which I need to implement a multiselection list as the example below,
Do you have any idea of a library that can help me do it.

thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: From the close vote text: Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

the best option i've found is select2 (https://select2.github.io/). It supports multi-select and all the usual goodies, based on jquery.

Comment: In fact I searched in the examples, there was not the possibility of selecting the parent and only one child or selecting that the parent without childrens

Comment: ah that's too bad, select2 is the one i usually use but i've never had quite as complex of a scenario as you descibe. Perhaps you could accomplish this behavior with some custom js in addition to select2